# Transform list of strings of commit-details to structured dictionary applying grouping by name and date

Tags: python, json, regex, grouping

From the data I have, I want to show in such form where a commit key will have an array
of commits that are done on the particular date. This is what I am expecting my output to be

```
{
    "Dan Ab": [
        {
            "2014-05-2": {
                "commit_count": "1",
                "commit": [{ 'commit_hash': {'lines_added': 10, 'lines_removed': 4 }}]
            },
            "2014-05-3": {
                "commit_count": "2",
                "commit": [
                    { 'commit_hash': {'lines_added': 10, 'lines_removed': 4 }},
                    { 'commit_hash': {'lines_added': 14, 'lines_removed': 0 }},
                ]
            },
        }
    ],
    "John": [
        "2020-10-14": {
            "commit_count": "1",
            "commit": [{ 'commit_hash': {'lines_added': 1740, 'lines_removed': 10 }}]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, the same date are shown multiple times instead of appending commit related information as in above for a particular date, and for particular author.

This is how I have done and is not working

```
import re

merged_result = [
    "43f4cc160;Dan Ab;2021-06-17; 1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 19 deletions(-)",
    "6cbf2a8b3;Dan Ab;2021-06-15; 1 file changed, 14303 insertions(+)",
    "c0a77029c;Dan Ab;2021-06-15; 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)",
    "f283d7524;Dan Ab;2021-06-15; 1 file changed, 5260 deletions(-)",
    "03c5314b4;Dan Ab;2021-06-15; 5 files changed, 5265 insertions(+), 12690 deletions(-)",
    "daf38ecdf;Dan Ab;2020-12-11; 1 file changed, 8 insertions(+)",
    "b5eabd543;Dan Ab;2020-10-14; 1 file changed, 17 insertions(+)",
    "6d50a9d09;Dan Ab;2020-10-14; 43 files changed, 15740 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)",
    "7d59n9d09;John;2020-10-14; 4 files changed, 1740 insertions(+), 10 deletion(-)"
]
coding_days = {}
total_lines = 0
total_lines_added = 0
total_lines_removed = 0
total_files_changed = 0


def getstatsummarycounts(line):
    """
    1 file changed, 5 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-) - returns ['1', '5', '1']
    """
    numbers = re.findall("\d+", line)
    if len(numbers) == 1:
        # neither insertions nor deletions: may probably only happen
        # for "0 files changed"
        numbers.append(0)
        numbers.append(0)
    elif len(numbers) == 2 and line.find("(+)") != -1:
        numbers.append(0)  # only insertions were printed on line
    elif len(numbers) == 2 and line.find("(-)") != -1:
        numbers.insert(1, 0)  # only deletions were printed on line
    return numbers


for result in merged_result:
    [commit_hash, author, commit_date, logs] = result.split(";")
    numbers = getstatsummarycounts(logs)
    if len(numbers) == 3:
        (files_changed, inserted, deleted) = map(lambda el: int(el), numbers)
        total_lines += inserted
        total_lines -= deleted
        total_lines_added += inserted
        total_lines_removed += deleted
        total_files_changed += files_changed
        if author not in coding_days:
            coding_days[author] = []
        else:
            if commit_date not in coding_days[author]:
                coding_days[author].append({commit_date: []})
            else:
                coding_days[author][0][commit_date].append({
                    commit_hash: {
                        "lines_added": inserted,
                        "lines_deleted": deleted,
                    }
                })
    else:
        (files_changed, inserted, deleted) = (0, 0, 0)
```

I have created a repl of it as well and here it is

https://replit.com/@xedikaki/EnragedHotSymbol#main.py

Comment: you have a list too much - why does `Dan Ab": [ ...]` need a list? it can directly contain the dict of dates.

Comment: There will be a data for multiple authors. So I wanted to arrange the list based on authors and inside each author, it should be arranged based on date. There might be a design problem in my expected output and I am okay to change the design but main thing is there will be multiple authors and it should be based on author and each author should have commit related data based on date where each commit's addition, deletions are shown.

Comment: Your are totally right. It will be different. Sorry, for showing few data. I did not include the other author's data.

Comment: Still ... `"Dan Ab" :[]` will NEVER have more then one Dict in his List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse and restructure your data like so:

```
merged_result = [
    "43f4cc160;Dan Ab;2021-06-17; 1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 19 deletions(-)",
    "6cbf2a8b3;Dan Ab;2021-06-15; 1 file changed, 14303 insertions(+)",
    "c0a77029c;Dan Ab;2021-06-15; 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)",
    "f283d7524;Dan Ab;2021-06-15; 1 file changed, 5260 deletions(-)",
    "03c5314b4;Dan Ab;2021-06-15; 5 files changed, 5265 insertions(+), 12690 deletions(-)",
    "daf38ecdf;Dan Ab;2020-12-11; 1 file changed, 8 insertions(+)",
    "b5eabd543;Dan Ab;2020-10-14; 1 file changed, 17 insertions(+)",
    "6d50a9d09;Dan Ab;2020-10-14; 43 files changed, 15740 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)",
    "6d50a9d09;Dan Ab;2020-10-14; Steak and Fries, no Salad",
]
```

Program:

```
import re

grouped = {}
pattern = r"(\d+) file[^,]*(?:\, (\d+) ins[^,]+)?(?:\, (\d+) del.+)?$"

for line in merged_result:
    tag, name, date, changes = line.split(";", 3)
    try:
        # this will throw "NoneType" has no .groups() if not matched
        files, inserts, deletes = re.search(pattern, changes).groups()
        inserts, deletes = inserts or "0", deletes or "0"
    except AttributeError as a:
        print("Skipping: '",line, 
              "': cannot match data by regex to get changed/inserted/deleted\n", a)
        continue
    
    nameDict = grouped.setdefault(name, {})
    dateDict = nameDict.setdefault(date, {})
    dateDict.setdefault("commit_count", 0)
    dateDict["commit_count"] += 1
    commList = dateDict.setdefault("commit", [])
    commList.append({"commit_hash": {"tag": tag, "files": files, 
                     "lines_added": inserts, "lines_removed": deletes}})

print(grouped)
```

Output:

```
Skipping: ' 6d50a9d09;Dan Ab;2020-10-14; Steak and Fries, no Salad ': cannot match data by regex to get changed/inserted/deleted

{'Dan Ab': {'2021-06-17': {'commit_count': 1, 'commit': [{'commit_hash': {'tag': '43f4cc160', 'files': '1', 'lines_added': '10', 'lines_removed': '19'}}]}, '2021-06-15': {'commit_count': 4, 'commit': [{'commit_hash': {'tag': '6cbf2a8b3', 'files': '1', 'lines_added': '14303', 'lines_removed': '0'}}, {'commit_hash': {'tag': 'c0a77029c', 'files': '1', 'lines_added': '1', 'lines_removed': '1'}}, {'commit_hash': {'tag': 'f283d7524', 'files': '1', 'lines_added': '0', 'lines_removed': '5260'}}, {'commit_hash': {'tag': '03c5314b4', 'files': '5', 'lines_added': '5265', 'lines_removed': '12690'}}]}, '2020-12-11': {'commit_count': 1, 'commit': [{'commit_hash': {'tag': 'daf38ecdf', 'files': '1', 'lines_added': '8', 'lines_removed': '0'}}]}, '2020-10-14': {'commit_count': 2, 'commit': [{'commit_hash': {'tag': 'b5eabd543', 'files': '1', 'lines_added': '17', 'lines_removed': '0'}}, {'commit_hash': {'tag': '6d50a9d09', 'files': '43', 'lines_added': '15740', 'lines_removed': '1'}}]}}}
```

Resulting dict [reformatted](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) (1st hit on google):

```
{
    "Dan Ab":{
        "2021-06-17":{
            "commit_count":1,
            "commit":[
                {
                    "commit_hash":{
                        "tag":"43f4cc160",
                        "files":"1",
                        "lines_added":"10",
                        "lines_removed":"19"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "2021-06-15":{
            "commit_count":4,
            "commit":[
                {
                    "commit_hash":{
                        "tag":"6cbf2a8b3",
                        "files":"1",
                        "lines_added":"14303",
                        "lines_removed":"0"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "commit_hash":{
                        "tag":"c0a77029c",
                        "files":"1",
                        "lines_added":"1",
                        "lines_removed":"1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "commit_hash":{
                        "tag":"f283d7524",
                        "files":"1",
                        "lines_added":"0",
                        "lines_removed":"5260"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "commit_hash":{
                        "tag":"03c5314b4",
                        "files":"5",
                        "lines_added":"5265",
                        "lines_removed":"12690"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "2020-12-11":{
            "commit_count":1,
            "commit":[
                {
                    "commit_hash":{
                        "tag":"daf38ecdf",
                        "files":"1",
                        "lines_added":"8",
                        "lines_removed":"0"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "2020-10-14":{
            "commit_count":2,
            "commit":[
                {
                    "commit_hash":{
                        "tag":"b5eabd543",
                        "files":"1",
                        "lines_added":"17",
                        "lines_removed":"0"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "commit_hash":{
                        "tag":"6d50a9d09",
                        "files":"43",
                        "lines_added":"15740",
                        "lines_removed":"1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

---

Explanation for `r"(\d+) file[^,]*(?:\, (\d+) ins[^,]+)?(?:\, (\d+) del.+)?$"`:

I am using `re.search` so it is not bound to start at the begin of the string - I am looking for:

```
(\d+) file[^,]          a number followed by "file" consuming
                        anything up to (excluding) the next ","
                        capturing the number in a group

(?:\, (\d+) ins[^,]+)?
(?:\, (\d+) del.+)?     are similar: 0 to 1 occurence of ", "
                        followed by a captured number
                        followed by a space and some text
                        after "ins" we capture anyting up to excluding
                        the next ","
                        after "del" we simply capture anything

$                       followed by end of string
```

the optional groups will result in `None` if not present, hence converting them to 0 using `inserts, deletes = inserts or "0", deletes or "0"`

If you need *more speed* you could use `defaultdict()` but `dict.setdefault` does the trick as well.

Comment: This git analyzer is my first project on pure python. Thank you very much for your time on this wonderful explanation and solution. The code is written in such a cleaner way that it motivated me to look after the topics like defaultDict and many such more apis of python.

Comment: Since you mentioned about the speed using defaultdict(), can I ask you if numpy will better suit for this by converting python list to numpy array? It's because, I noticed there might be 10k + data.

Comment: @Serenity I wouldn't. You can simply double up on the data you gave me - I did it up to 5k lines and my PC handles this in ~11 seconds - most of which is print statements which you can speed up by writing into a file instead. Is speed critical? If you have 10k+ elements you are not really tackling "live" data so what if it takes a minute or two? But if you feel you need to optimize, do so, you got a starting point :)